# OpenGL: How to update only a portion of a texture?

Tags: c++, opengl

I dont want to update the whole texture every time i change a small part of it, what is the command for this?

And when i have mipmapping on, set with GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, how optimized is that internally? will it calculate whole image again, or just the part i updated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

glTexSubImage2D.

Mipmap generation process is implementation dependant, it probably will update the whole mipmap chain.

Comment: I guess it has to update the whole chain, because everything could possibly change if you change something at level 0, and i cannot imagine any way of figuring out if changes to level 0 wont affect level N...